# How to remove Notepad from the applications list?

Tags: xfce, wine, open-files, mime-types

After installing Wine, Notepad has became a default application to open unknown textual files by double click. I'd like to eliminate this behaviour and remove Notepad from the list of applications offered to open an unknown type file. I've deleted `/usr/share/applications/wine-notepad.desktop`, but this didn't help. How can I disable Notepad correctly?

I use XUbuntu 11.10 (XFCE 4.8) and Wine 1.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had that problem too some months ago, and I remember I had to delete some `.desktop` files that were inside the `$HOME/.local/share/applications` folder.
I think you should delete any file that has `notepad` as part of its name, and also you should try to delete (or move somewhere else) the files `wine-extension-*`.

Comment: The only file you need to delete or rename is `wine-extension-txt.desktop`. This associates `MimeType=text/plain` with Windows Notepad.

Answer (score 3):

Modify `/usr/share/applications/wine-notepad.desktop`, adding the line:

```
Hidden=true
```

There is a bit more information about what that does [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html). Alternatively, you could probably just delete that file instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow the instructions here to disable this behavior altogether:

http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-c847a3ded88bac0e61aae0037fa7dbd4c7ae042a

Although you'll still need to follow the steps in [nozimica's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23314/14436) to get rid of existing associations.

Answer (score 0):

For [archlinux](/questions/tagged/archlinux), I have done :

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
rm wine-extension-*
```